# provability of a mathematical statement

Tags: provability

Is it possible to prove that a non-axiom statement is not mathematically provable with current accepted axioms of mathematics?

Note that this is not a question of proving if it is a true or false statement, but a proof that it is impossible to make a statement of the validity of the statement.

for extra clarification: Gödel's incompleteness theorems state that there are true statements that are unprovable. My question is are there statements that cannot have their validity proven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many sentences $\varphi$ that have been shown to be neither provable nor refutable from the axioms of ZFC (if that theory is consistent). The most famous example is the continuum hypothesis. Please [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_undecidable_in_ZFC) for a very long list.